# How do I configure emacs to print?

Tags: emacs, printing

I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and I would like to print just by doing `M-x print-buffer`. When I do this, nothing seems to happen right now.

I'm using the [Cocoa-ified GUI version of Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs will print however the default printer is configured. For whatever reason my wireless printer wasn't connecting to my router, that was the issue. So for any one running into this problem, the problem lies with Mac OS X not connecting to the printer. It isn't an emacs issue.